# C++ - Problemas con porcentajes en arreglo

Tags: c++, array, porcentaje

Tengo un arreglo donde quiero sacar el porcentaje de entre un total que ya calcule y el monto total de un vendedor.

Por alguna razon, cuando agrego 2 vendedores pero solo a uno le agrego valor, funciona, pero cuando los dos tienen valor, a vienta el porcentaje de 0.

En la tercer linea de codigo adjunta, estoy imprimiendo la formula para sacar los decimales a porcentuar. 
    En ejemplo: suma[0] = 2, sumaTotal=2, imprime: 1 / 2, pero si es suma[0]=1, suma[1]=1, sumaTotal = 2, en el cout aparece "1 / 2", pero el porcentaje aparece con valor de cero.

```
int suma[4]={0},totalVendedor = 4,sumaTotal;
double porcentaje[4]={0}
for(int ad=0;ad<totalVendedor;ad++){
    porcentaje[ad] = (suma[ad]/sumaTotal)*100;
    cout<<suma[ad]<<"/"<<sumaTotal<<endl;
    cout<<vendedor[ad].nombre<<" - "<<porcentaje[ad]<<"%"<<endl;
}
```

Espero haber explicado correctamente.

Comment: Si no pones los tipos de las variables es dificil ayudarte

Comment: Cambia de `int` a `float` o a `double` para solucionar el problema